# Form_for is giving me a No Method Error when trying to create a new object

Tags: ruby-on-rails

So as it stands I have a form partial which starts off as:

```
<%= form_for(@merchandise) do |f| %>
```

It works perfectly for editing the data that I have already assigned in the rails console. When I try to use it for a "new" form that creates new merchandise (in this case the singular form of merchandise, I don't have nested resources, multiple models etc.), I get a no Method error that states

`"undefined method 'merchandises_path' for #<#<Class:0x64eaef0>:0x95d2370>".`

When I explicitly state the URL in the form_for method:

```
<%= form_for(@merchandise url:new_merchandise_path) do |f| %>
```

I get it to open and I finally have access to the form, however in this case I get a routing error that states

`"No route matches [POST] "merchandise/new""`.

I decided to write out that route in my routes file which previously just had:
root "merchandise#index" resources :merchandise

After I add the route it literally does nothing. I click submit and it takes me to the form but there is no new data in the database. I am at a complete loss and have been at this for hours googling and stack overflowing and I just don't know what to do anymore. All help is seriously appreciated. I'm adding a pastebin with all my code in the following url:

http://pastebin.com/HDJdTMDt

Comment: I think it's because you have your route resource in plural **resources** and your controller and name of route it's in singular **:merchandise**, so I think one solution and easy is write the route resource in singular in your case:
**resource** it's work for me so, let me know if you have problems

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have two options for you to fix it:

*Option 1:*

Please try to do this for best practice in Rails:

**routes.rb**

change your routes use plural

```
resources :merchandises
```

**merchandises_controller.rb**

Rename your file controller and class into `MerchandisesController`

```
class MerchandisesController < ApplicationController

        def index
                @merchandise = Merchandise.all
        end

        def new
                @merchandise = Merchandise.new
        end

        def create
                @merchandise = Merchandise.new(merchandise_params)
                if @merchandise.save
                        redirect_to merchandises_path
                else
                        render :new
                end
        end

        def show
                @merchandise = Merchandise.find(params[:id])
        end

        def edit
                @merchandise = Merchandise.find(params[:id])
        end

        def update
                @merchandise = Merchandise.find(params[:id])
                if @merchandise.update(merchandise_params)
                redirect_to @merchandise, notice: "The movie was updated"
        else
                render :edit
        end
        end

        def merchandise_params
                params.require(:merchandise).permit(:shipper, :cosignee, :country_arrival_date, :warehouse_arrival_date, :carrier, :tracking_number, :pieces, :palets, :width, :height, :length, :weight, :description, :cargo_location, :tally_number, :customs_ref_number, :released_date, :updated_by, :country_shipped_to, :country_shipped_from)
        end

end
```

*Option 2:*

If you want to not change many code

**/merchandise/_form.html.erb**

in partial file

**/merchandise/new.html.erb**

```
<%= render 'form', url: merchandise_path, method: 'post' %>
```

**/merchandise/edit.html.erb**

```
<%= render 'form', url: category_path(@merchendise.id), method: 'put' %>
```

Comment: option1  is the way to go!

Comment: Option 1 was indeed the way to go. Thank you my friend!